# There is a problem when creating a release with Git(Hub) branches

Tags: github, version, branch, conflict, semantic-release

We're serving a Node.js application and operating branch policy on GitHub such as:

- `main`: Production environment release base
- `develop`: Development environment (beta) release base

Basically, we're writing some code on a new branch from the `develop` branch and merging it into the `develop` and then merging the `develop` into the `main`.
In hotfix cases, fix a code on a new branch from the `main` and then merge it into `develop` and `main`.

The release is processed by semantic-release, and automatically changes the `package.json` file and `CHANGELOG.md` file in CI/CD pipeline.

> Which means that semantic-release commit to the release target branch and the file gets changed.

### So, we have a problem in the case below:

- If there are changes in the `develop` branch, a version is increased as a beta.
- If there are hotfixes in the `main` branch, a version is increased.
- When merging the `main` into the `develop`, occurring conflict.

> Because, the files changed and committed them at the same time.
> This case is trying to reflect the recent version into the `develop` branch.
> We're expecting the same phenomenon when merging the `develop` into the `main`.

We're feeling the hassle to fix the conflict and worry about the wrong change when occurred this case.

Should we have to DO NOT MERGE the `main` into the `develop`?

We want to know how do you build your release pipeline.

Thank you.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. Did you find a solution about that ?